# Why lombok does not use a maven plugin and requieres an Eclipse plugin, Java module dependency or Windows exe

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, lombok

I don't really get why would Lombok require a special IDE related plugin to process dependencies when things Like Spring Boot (or any other compile-time annotation) do not require it. Is it because from a compile point of view the kind of changes that Lombok does are not in the same "page" as the kind of compile procesing that a maven dependency would be able to apply?

Many pom plugins have related M2E plugins, so I am inclined to believe that would be the way to go (unless someone at lombok hates M2E which would make sense)

Comment: No other dependency comes to mind, which generates code that you can use directly after applying an annotation. I.e. lomboks `@Getter` allows you directly to use the getter methods within eclipse, without eclipse complaining about it. Afaik, no other dependency has a functionality like this. And to have eclipse not complain about "missing" methods, lombok needs to alter the eclipse instance, hence requiring an eclipse plugin

Comment: Lombok is a hack (a useful hack, but a hack nonetheless). It modifies the same source file that's being compiled by "breaking into" the compiler implementation. "Normal" compile-time annotation processors "can't do that". The public API only allows you to generate _new_ sources, not modify existing sources. And the changes Lombok make aren't actually visible until during and after compilation. So, IDEs typically need a plugin that is Lombok-aware in order to work properly (i.e., so code suggestions work, errors aren't reported incorrectly, etc.).

Comment: Guys feel free to reply with those comments, both are acceptable answers

Comment: And because Lombok is a hack your code has suddenly become brittle. If for any reason Lombok stops to be maintained your code will eventually stop to compile.